# Is it possible to check drawing mode in shader and change some vertex attr accordingly?

Tags: opengl, shader

Im working on an OpenGL project where i have to draw a colored gridblock as well as (white/black) lines bordering each cell in the block.

The vertices locations composing the cells are the same as the ones used for the lines(borders).. however they will be colored when used to draw faces(triangles), and have static color when used to draw the lines.

so my question is, is there a way to know the drawing mode inside the shader and assign the static color if GL_LINES was used, else use the color in the VBO ?

EDIT: a 2nd question just popped into my head.. If I use the same vertices to draw both the triangles and the lines, will the lines be obscured by the faces or is it the other way around?

Comment: Encode the drawing mode in a uniform?

Comment: "If I use the same vertices to draw both the triangles and the lines, will the lines be obscured by the faces or is it the other way around?" That's a separate question. And it depends on whether you've got depth testing active as well as the order you're rendering things.

Comment: @genpfault care to elaborate plz ?

Comment: @NicolBolas, well the vertices are on the same coordinates.. so idk how Depth testing will handle it ..maybe the rendering order will affect the output, so whatever gets drawn last obscures what was drawn first .. isnt that what you are saying ?

Comment: @MostafaWasat: See Nicol's second bullet point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertex shaders are not able to know what the primitive type they are being used for.

The general ways of solving this are:

- Change programs between drawing static and dynamic colors. Have a different program based on whether the color comes from an input array or a uniform.
- Uber-shader style. Have a uniform specify whether to use a static or dynamic color. This, for example, is totally legal:

  ```
  uniform bool is_color_static;

  in vec4 dyn_color;
  uniform vec4 static_color;

  void use_color(in vec4 color) {...}

  void main()
  {
    if(is_color_static)
      use_color(static_color);
    else
      use_color(dyn_color);
  }
  ```

  This is typically used in high-end games to prevent having to swap shaders a lot. For your use case, it's probably excessive. But it does have the advantage of you having fewer shader files to worry about and bug-fix.
- Use [unarrayed attributes](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Non-array_attribute_values). When you `glDisableVertexAttribArray` for an attribute, and your shader looks at that value anyway, the value the shader gets comes from a piece of global state. This global state can be set with the `glVertexAttrib` functions. The performance characteristics of this are unknown, as little code uses it. It's also likely to be buggy.

Comment: Yea i think i get it now, all i have to do is set the uniform bool is_color_static to true prior to drawing the lines and reset it afterwards? am i getting this right ?..